# What happens when someone accessed you league account on another computer?

Tags: league-of-legends

What happens if you're in a league game on computer 1 and it goes really well, Then the guy you share your league account with opens league to also play?

Comment: **Account sharing is a terrible idea!** No matter how much you trust someone.

Comment: Account sharing is against the terms of service, and if the both of you were to login at the same time there is every possibility that the game would detect the login from two different IP addresses, and you would be at risk of losing your account altogether.

Comment: What happens when you try this? It seems like something that you should be able to test yourself.

Comment: For most games, the first session would be kicked (disconnected)... And I think this is the case for LoL - I did this a couple of years back, and the first client displays the disconnected errors until I restarted the client.

Comment: thanks for the response guys. I don't share any account of mine but I used to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sharing your account with someone and they login while you are in a game, the person in the game will be kicked off of the client and the person logging in will see the message "Game is still in progress... please reconnect".